# Linux Change Modification date of files?

Tags: php, linux, find, touch

I extract .php files in one of my directory and there were many files in there so most of the files replaced !

but I have a problem since the modification date of new files are 23 April 2013 so I want to find all files and folders in this directory that are not 23 April 2013 !

In other way, I want to change all files in this directory that have 23 April 2013 modification date to 30/08/2013 !

How its possible to find and change the files ?

Combine **FIND** and **TOUCH** function to replace all files modification date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could `cd` to the folder containing the PHP files and:

```
touch -d '30 August 2013' *.php
```

Or if it has sub folders with php files - search through them recursively:

```
find /path/to/your/php/ -exec touch -d '30 August 2013' *.php {} \;
```

the folder 'php' in the command above would be included.

**Edit:**

If you ONLY need to find/change EXACTLY files modified on 23 April 2013, you can use the `-mtime` parameter in your find command.

- `-mtime +60` means you are looking for a file modified 60 days ago or more.
- `-mtime -60` means less than 60 days.
- `-mtime 60` If you skip `+` or `-` it means exactly 60 days.

So modifying the command above like this:

```
find /path/to/your/php/ -mtime 127 -exec touch -d '30 August 2013' *.php {} \;
```

Where 127 is the exact amount of days since 23 April (if my quick head calculation is correct). Else you can change the number to the correct amount of days, or use the `+` or `-` as described above if it doesn't need to be 'that' exact.

You can read more about the find commands -mtime parameter here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/

(yes I borrowed 3 lines from there)